# Power apps substitute for a column in a collection

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-collection

I have created a powerapp logic that takes input from a textinput control and then compares the content with a collection and when matched it substitues the text with the value in the 2nd column of the collection i.e.

if textinput1.text = collection.column 1, substitute textinput1.text value with collection.column2.

Issue i am having is that it is doing this multiple times for each value of the textinput thereby creating multiple rows of output - see query and output attached
[image]

here acronym and meaning are columns in the CollectParam collection - see the output
[image]

i will like to have just one line text with the acronymns i.e. A&M and AAE replaced with their full descriptions from the meaning column . I am doing a split on the textinput since thats the only way i could compare with the acronym column. Thanks for your assistance on this effort